# Logging in after LinkedIn Auth in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, oauth

I received all of the standard data in the form of `$this->data` from Linkedin.

What do I save as a password to make `$this->Auth->login()` work?

Here is my code:

```
    public function opauth_complete() {
        $conditions = array(
    'User.email' => $this->data['auth']['info']['email']
);
if ($this->User->hasAny($conditions)){
    debug($this->data);
    $this->request->data['User']['username'] =  //what do I put here?
    $this->request->data['User']['password'] =  //what do I put here?
    //login stuff
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
else {

     //register stuff
}

   }
```

Comment: The user's username and password, I'd imagine.

Comment: Lol. Right except when you authenticate with LinkedIn you don't receive a standard username and password.

Comment: LinkedIn oAuth gives things like `['credentials']['token']` and `['credentials']['expires']` and all kinds of others. So I'm trying to figure out what I save/check against in order to authenticate properly.

Comment: I assume that you are trying to implement a "login with social network xyz" functionality? If so then why do you need to save/check anything after you've already authenticated the user with LinkedIn? Have you read and understand [**how `AuthComponent::login()` works**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in)? Also there isn't necessarily the need to reinvent the wheel: **https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth**

Comment: thanks this is helpful. I see that I don't have to feed authcomponent params - but after logging in and redirecting, I can't get things like `AuthComponent::user('id')` to work - which leads me to believe I'm not logged in properly still.